# Configure timestamp format in promtail loki logfile chain

Tags: grafana

I'm using a toolstack of promtail, loki, grafana running in docker.
I want to [configure the date format of the timestamp](https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/master/docs/clients/promtail/stages/timestamp.md) in my log files.

This is a part of my promtail configuration:

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: mylogs
  pipeline_stages:
   - timestamp:
      source: time
      format: RFC3339
```

I created a logfile containing these lines:

```
time=2020-01-02T15:04:05-07:00 message=bla
ts=2020-01-02T15:04:05-07:00 message=bla
2020-01-02T15:04:05-07:00 message=bla
```

But as a can see in the grafana gui, the timestamp was not recognized in any of these lines.
My questions:

- Is the timestamp configuration correct?
- How should the lines in the logfile look like?

Comment: 1) uppercase "Z" character MUST be present in the absence of a numeric time zone offset (https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/error/InvalidRFC3339Date.html). See examples: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.8). 


2)  json format is the easiest to start with(see https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/master/docs/clients/promtail/stages/json.md#using-log-line). For other logfile formats more configuration is needed for [pipeline stages](]https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/master/docs/clients/promtail/pipelines.md).

Comment: hi, did you resolve this issue? i have line 'timestamp=2021-09-27T15:01:08Z elapsed=1913' and that's rule for parse:                                                                            
         - timestamp:
          format: RFC3339
          source: timestamp. But it doesn't recognize my timestamp